# "Something unusual in them" vs "something unusual about them"

Tags: word-choice

Example:

> "Did you notice anything unusual **in** the cows during the day?"
>
> "Did you notice anything unusual **about** the cows during the day?"

What's the correct wording? And why?

Comment: Both are correct, but have slightly different meanings. "In" pertains to something intrinsic, something "personal", whereas "about" relates to the vicinity, outward behavior.

Comment: Having thought more about it, I'd probably say that, when speaking of **cows**, people are unlikely to say ***in***, and more likely to say ***about***, since we can't really easily judge the mental or even physical state of another being, let alone of a different species.  So, "**about** the cows" is probably *more* correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Did you notice anything unusual **about the cows** during the day?

is correct. See [***about***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/about):

> 17. in connection with; pertaining to"   ⇒ *the most interesting thing about her*"

*in the cows* is more like something inside the cows. But you could say:

> Did you notice anything unusual **in the barn** during the day?

You could also use *with*. See [***with***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/with):

> 5b. regarding; concerning"   ⇒ *with him, life is always a struggle*"